# If condition is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Jquery-Assignment</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container,
        .container2 {
            width: 49%;
            border-right: 5px solid #000;
            float: left;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }
        .container2 {
            border: none;
        }
        .controls {
            padding-bottom: 50px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .ball,
        .ball2 {
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #000;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="controls"> <span><a href="#" id="prev"><img src="arrow-prev.png"/></a></span> <span><a href="#" id="next"><img src="arrow-next.png"/></a></span> </div>
            <div class="ball-path">
                <div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="controls"> <span><a href="#" id="prev"><img src="arrow-prev.png"/></a></span> <span><a href="#" id="next"><img src="arrow-next.png"/></a></span> </div>
            <div class="ball-path">
                <div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var n;
        var w = $(".container").width();
        var b = $("#ball").width();
        var pos = (w - b + 'px');
        $('#next').on('click', function() {
            n = $("#ball").css("left") debugger;
            if (n <= pos) {
                $("#ball").animate({
                    left: '+=20'
                }, 1);
            } else {
                $("#ball").animate({
                    left: '+=0'
                }, 1);
            }
        });
        $('#prev').on('click', function() {
            n = $("#ball").css("left") if (n == '0px') {
                $("#ball").animate({
                    left: '-=0'
                }, 1);
            } else {
                $("#ball").animate({
                    left: '-=20'
                }, 1);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: the left position is increased by 20px; so  if the width of the container is 600 OR 620 OR 640  then it is working but when i use box sizing property then with became like 615px because border is 5 px. then the smaller then condition is not working. Please suggest any answer for that.

If any body is not able to under stand the words above then please add and remove box sizing property.

Comment: Put a `;` after `n = $("#ball").css("left")`

Comment: I have corrected that, but no effect

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understand u clearly. But the thing is if u use border-box, it makes/forces the width to includes border&padding

Comment: yes padding is added in width but then the jquery condition is not working. Do you have any answer for that pls